# XPages SSJS setValue or replaceItemValue

Tags: xpages-ssjs

On pressing a save button I have code in a script editor to grab a field, split it up and place those parts into other fields on the XPage which are bound to fields on a form. However, getComponent("x").setValue("1") works, but the currentDocument.save() won't save those changes. If I use currentDocument.replaceItemValue("x", "1") they get saved. Why? What if the difference in how I set those fields? Is it like front-end save vs back-end save?

Comment: `getComponent()` is slower and should be avoided when possible. Looks like you don't really have a problem here.

Comment: Whent he field was set with getComponent and I then saved the doc the changes weren't saved and I wondered why. As you say, not a problem using replaceItemValue anyway. Thanks Panu.